# Outline (circumference) polygon extraction from contiguous patch of equal squares

Tags: algorithm, matlab, computational-geometry

Referring to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44420407/4023805) where given a contiguous patch of square grid-cells (yellow cells), we had to extract a perimeter polygon by joining centres of outlying cells.

My question is how to extract that perimeter polygon which is formed from the edges of the outlying grid-cells meaning the green polygon in figure below.

[image]

I am not posing this as an image processing question. It is purely a geometrical problem because the input is the yellow grid cells known in array form like: `indices=[64,65,88,89,90....`. Input is not the image of the yellow cells in pink background. That is only a visualization.

The code to generate an outer polygons from centers of the cells is given here:-

```
clear;
close all;
A=ones(25,25);
indices=[64,65,88,89,90,91,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,307,308,309,310,311,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,341,342,343,344,345,367,368,369,393,394];
A(indices)=2;

figure
hold on
axis equal
axis ij
xx=10:20:500;
yy=10:20:500;
imagesc(xx,yy,A);
colormap([1.0000         0    0.7931;
    1.0000    0.8276         0]);
rt=[0,500];
gcs=0:20:500;
gds=ones(size(rt,2),size(gcs,2));
gds = bsxfun(@times,gds,gcs);
plot(rt,gds,'Color','k','LineStyle','-');
plot(gds,rt,'Color','k','LineStyle','-');
axis([0 350 100 450])

A=A-1;
% we identify patterns with edges over 2x2 patches, describing with
% the first 4 binary values what pixels are set, and with the next 2
% the edge with 2 indices over the 2x2 patch
patterns = [
    0,1,0,1,  3,4 % vertical edge at rhe right
    1,0,1,0,  1,2 % vertical edge at the left
    0,0,1,1,  2,4 % horizontal edge at the bottom
    1,1,0,0,  1,3 % horizontal edge at the top
    1,0,0,1,  1,4 % diagonal edge
    0,1,1,0,  2,3 % diagonal edge
    1,0,1,1,  1,4 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
    1,1,0,1,  1,4 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
    1,1,1,0,  2,3 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
    0,1,1,1,  2,3 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
    ];

% 2x2 patches (matrix form)
P00 = A(1:end-1,1:end-1);
P10 = A(2:end,1:end-1);
P01 = A(1:end-1,2:end);
P11 = A(2:end,2:end);

% edge unique identifier using powers of 2
id = @(p00,p01,p10,p11) 1*p00 + 2*p10 + 4*p01 + 8*p11;
P = id(P00,P01,P10,P11); % vectorized pattern identification

% edges
e0 = []; % from (i,j)
e1 = []; % to (i,j)
for i = 1:size(patterns, 1) % small loop over the 10 patterns
    p = patterns(i, :);
    E = (P == id(p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4))); % pattern search, vectorized
    [c,r] = ind2sub(size(E), find(E));
    [c0,r0] = ind2sub([2,2], p(5));
    [c1,r1] = ind2sub([2,2], p(6));
    e0 = [e0; c+c0, r+r0];
    e1 = [e1; c+c1, r+r1];
end

X = [e0(:,2) e1(:,2)]';
Y = size(A,1) - [e0(:,1) e1(:,1)]';
X=X*20; X=X-30;
Y=Y*20; Y=470-Y;

XY_from = [X(1, :)' Y(1, :)' zeros(size(X, 2), 1)]; 
XY_to = [X(2, :)' Y(2, :)' zeros(size(X, 2), 1)]; 
new_poly = zeros(size(X, 2)+1, 2); 
new_poly(1, :) = XY_from(1, 1:2); 
for i=2:size(new_poly, 1)
  index = find(all([new_poly(i-1, :) 0] == XY_from, 2), 1); 
  if isempty(index) 
    index = find(all([new_poly(i-1, :) 0] == XY_to, 2), 1); 
    new_poly(i, :) = XY_from(index, 1:2); 
  else
    new_poly(i, :) = XY_to(index, 1:2); 
  end
  XY_from(index, 3) = 1; 
  XY_to(index, 3) = 1; 
end
hold on
plot(new_poly(:, 1), new_poly(:, 2), '--b', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33472951/4023805) but it is not a Matlabby solution and seems to be directed towards image processing.

Comment: How do you define a perimeter? By the coordinates of its vertices? Would those coordinates be non-integer (since cell centers are integer)?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Your question should be self-contained.  In particular, please give us the *full* input for this example.

Comment: The second part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230034/52738) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45203862/52738) shows how to do this using triangulation.

Comment: @LuisMendo The output is a polygon defined by nx2 array of its vertices and these vertices in this problem will simply be the outer vertices of the outer cells.

Comment: @LuisMendo The cell centers as well as the cell vertices are all integers. This fact may be used to exploit image processing techniques to solve this problem but i am looking at ti from comp geom pov.

Comment: You can do that in 2 lines using convolution, but if you want to walk the perimeter, it'll take a bit more coding.

Comment: Are you looking for an ordered set of perimeter coordinates, or just a way to plot the green lines?

Comment: @gnovice looking for an ordered set of perimeter coordinates and also to be able to plot the green lines using coordinates as a visual aid

Comment: @user_1_1_1: In that case, the second part of my answer ("Getting the outline coordinates") on the linked duplicate will do exactly what you want. You can use `mask = A>1; x = 1:25; y = 1:25;` (with the `A` you generate in your first few lines), then just run the code there and get your ordered edge coordinates in `xOutline` and `yOutline`.