# Google Maps API with polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

(excuse me for my bad english)
the tops of my polygon are stored into my database (latitude, longitude). so I recovered the latitude and longitude in a table and then I draw my polygon. my problem is that with 3 tops it works fine, but when it is more then 3 it gives this result:

[image: Map]

this is my code :

```
success: function(data) {
                             //   alert(data); 
                    var tableauPointsPolygone = new Array ();                          
                    var j=0;
                    var somme=0;
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                                tableauPointsPolygone.push(new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude));
                                somme+= parseInt(item.valeur);
                                j++;
                                addMarker(item.latitude,item.longitude,item.adr);
                                center = bounds.getCenter();
                                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    // alert(item.latitude);
});
var monPolygone = new google.maps.Polygon();
monPolygone.setPaths( tableauPointsPolygone );
monPolygone.setMap( map );
if (somme/j<5)
monPolygone.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3,strokeColor: '#582900' ,fillColor: '#1FA055'});
else
monPolygone.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3,strokeColor: '#582900' ,fillColor: '#A91101'});
                                },
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of *tops* is and I don't see a problem with the polygon (because I don't see a question).

Comment: thanks for your reply,i mean with tops corner or vertices. The problem is that it's not a polygon, it doesn't cover the whole surface.

Comment: Where does your data come from?  What is the data for the polygon in question?  Seems to me the vertices just need to be reordered.

Comment: i have a table on my database named "capteur" where i stock all the point. but i have no idea how to reorder it lol

Comment: i added to my requet "order by longitude" and that work fine. thanks for your add

Comment: @geocodezip you might post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is the arrangement of polygon vertices. In case if 3 the order of point is not essential its triangle but in case of 4 and more you have to sort the points and then push into array.

[Here is a helpful question about convex (non-concave) polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533816/how-to-order-vertices-in-a-simple-non-convex-polygon)