# OSM - Boundary Export from XML file

Tags: mapping, gis, openstreetmap, polygons, boundary

I've been attempting to export boundary information from an OSM file.  My process is nearly there however I have an issue with the polygon I'm generating drawing random lines.

I would appreciate some insight on where I may be going wrong.

Step 1: Export the OSM data into XML

```
osmfilter -v greater-london-latest.osm --keep="boundary= admin_level= place="  > b.txt
```

Step 2: Run a script to process the XML.

```
cycle each relation node
 load the member ways
   load the nodes from each specified way
    record the lat/lon and build a poly set
```

This produces a series of lat/lon which when I build them as a polygon give the correct overall shape I'm looking for.  However, there are issues with the connecting lines I assume..

[My polygon output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAIOd.png)

I'm actually looking for this, which is similar but Im obviously missing something.

[Actual Poly Im looking to generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a10Mh.png)

Again, thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSM to Google Maps polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704706/osm-to-google-maps-polygons)

Answer (score 0):

Ways in relations are not necessarily sorted. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704706/osm-to-google-maps-polygons) on how to sort ways, especially the answer by user geocodezip.

Alternatively you can make use of various tools/libraries to do the sorting for you. Unfortunately I can't point you directly to one but there are various tools capable of sorting relation members, including the OSM website itself, JOSM, overpass turbo (I guess), some JS stuff, [...]. 
Maybe some other user can help out with pointing to some good examples?