# How to plot city in map via boundary line?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

How can I plot boundary line on `G-Map` on the basis of city searched like in this image red line showing searched city map?

[image: boundary line in map]

I have see various links but unable to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: related question: [OSM to Google Maps polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704706/osm-to-google-maps-polygons)

Answer (score 1):

Currently Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't expose any boundaries of geographic features. There is very old feature request in the public issue tracker to add this functionality, however it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953

Feel free to star the public feature request to express your interest and subscribe to notifications.

Also, you can find a workaround to get polygons from other sources and add them to Google maps as additional layers.

The nice workaround to get polygons in GeoJSON format from OSM is described in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172098/5140781

So, if you download the GeoJSON you will be able to add it to map using the data layer and its `loadGeoJson()` method:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson

I hope this helps!