# Method for obtaining the boundary range of a specified location(University Campus)

Tags: ios, google-maps

Recently, I have made an iOS map application, using the Google Maps for iOS SDK. I also succeeded in using GMSPolygon to draw a polygon on the map, and these areas were located on the map by human resources then displayed on the map. I know this is not an appropriate way, so I want to ask Google whether you have provided this kind of API for developers to call in order to obtain boundary longitude and latitude information of a designated university or business district. The effect is shown in the following picture.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbz59.png)

Comment: Google Maps APIs doesn't expose any boundary for features. Please read this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600181/5140781

Comment: First of all really thank you, I found a more cool tool under the reference link you gave，Here is a pretty cool tool, where you can draw the city border. You can be as exact as you like to be: http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html