# Get polygon shapefile/KML for a node/location in openstreetmap

Tags: python, openstreetmap, kml, shapefile, overpass-api

I have about 1000 nodes/locations of interest from openstreetmap. I queried Overpass API to get coordinates of those 1000 locations/nodes. What I am interested in is, getting a polygon based KML/shapefile for each of those 1000 locations. So basically, let's say I go to 1 of those 1000 locations on the map, currently I just have one location pointer for that location. But I need a whole polygon drawn for the location. For example, if it's a supermarket, I need a KML file for it such that it can show me a polygon drawn over the entire supermarket and not just a location pointer.

Is it possible to get that from Overpass API or anywhere else?
Thanks in advance.

Overpass API Query Sample:

```
/*
This query looks for nodes with the given key/value combination.
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “building=<xyz>”
  node["building"="<xyz>"];
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: How does your overpass query look like ?

Comment: ```
/*
This query looks for nodes with the given key/value combination.
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “building=<xyz>”
  node["building"="<xyz>"];
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Here's my query! Thanks for responding.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Please checkout the edit above. I've included the query sample in a more readable format. Thanks.

Comment: related question: [OSM to Google Maps polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704706/osm-to-google-maps-polygons)